# Accidental running of do-release-upgrade

Tags: upgrade

Accidentally I ran

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

And stopped it. But it seems it has changed my Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 sources and if I update the system it will be automatically upgraded.

How can I restore it to previous sources?

---

**Edit:**

I found these are unchecked:
[image]

So I rechecked them as in the image. However, I'm not sure if everything is as before.

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main restricted universe
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates main restricted universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-backports main restricted multiverse universe

# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security main restricted universe
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu saucy partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy main universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-security multiverse main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu saucy-updates multiverse main universe
```

and:

```
ponyo@ponyo-pc:~$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    core-2.0-ia32:core-2.0-noarch:core-3.0-ia32:core-3.0-noarch:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:core-3.2-ia32:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-ia32:core-4.0-noarch:core-4.1-ia32:core-4.1-noarch:security-4.0-ia32:security-4.0-noarch:security-4.1-ia32:security-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `lsb_release -a`?

Comment: @Braiam‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌:

Comment: I really don't see any problem. BTW, `do-release-upgrade -d` ask for confirmation, or that is what should happend...